# Scala String Interpolation with MAP Data structure

Tags: python, scala

In Python the string Interpolation can be done in many ways One of  the ways is substituting values from a Python dictionary where `a` and `b` are the keys in map

```
str = "Value of a is %(a)s and b is %(b)s"
```

I tried it in Scala

```
val data = Map(a->1, b->2)
val str = "Value of a is %(a)s and b is %(b)s"
```

Is there any better way to do the same in Scala as code I tried is not compiling and giving me the results?

Comment: Could you specify what is the intended behavior if the map has dozens of entries? Do you want to explicitly interpolate every entry?

Comment: Hi, if any of below answers has solved your problem please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the best answer or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.  There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @pedromss I want to generate SQL queries from entities in a Map DS. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could think of following ways without using appending.

```
val data = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)

// C/C++ way of applying variable values into String
println("Value of a is %ds and b is %ds".format(data("a"), data("b")))

//place variable inside ${} section of strings
println(s"Value of a is ${data("a")}s and b is ${data("b")}s")
```

Comment: I get a Some(1)  in my string when I use this way... I however got this while tinkering.. it should be ${data.get("a").get}

Comment: I tested my code in Scala 2.11 and working fine. What is the scala version you are using?

Comment: Mrsrinivas I am using Scala 2.11.11

Answer (score -1):

To use basic string interpolation in Scala, precede your string with the letter **s** and include your variables inside the string, with each variable name preceded by a **$** character. In case of an expression, enclose it with `${...}`

```
val data = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
println(s"${data.toList}".replace("List", ""))
```

**Result**

((a,1), (b,2))

The above approach will give you result for all the entries in the map rather than for one or few.